# how i can open a file in zip file without extract it by the PHP

Tags: php

i just want making a system that can open a file in a zip archive 
like i have archive.zip
in this file.text
i want make a class to makr this page
zip.php?archiver=archive.zip&file=file.text
i want this page show me the file.text contents
any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the PHP manual: [ZipArchive::getFromName()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-getfromname.php). This is exactly what you need.

```
<?php
$z = new ZipArchive();
if ($z->open(dirname(__FILE__) . '/test_im.zip')) {
    $string = $z->getFromName("mytext.txt");
    echo $string;
}
?>
```

Best wishes,
Fabian

Answer (score 1):

you could probably do this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ziparchive-getfromname.php

it's a function in http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php