# Poor performance of getting the contents of a jpg or a json file in a zipped versus unzipped directory

Tags: php, indexing, zip

I have a `a.zip` file with over 100K jpg images and 400K json files. I am able to get the contents of any file inside `a.zip` using `file_get_contents(zip:://path/to/a.zip#subdir/path/to/file)` function (in PHP). However, it takes about 100 times more time (from 250 milli-seconds to +25 seconds based on Firebug) to get the contents of the file compared to the unzipped directory. Would you suggest a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how i can open a file in zip file without extract it by the PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868035/how-i-can-open-a-file-in-zip-file-without-extract-it-by-the-php)

Comment: Solution.... extract all the images from your zip; and then you can always reference them directly from the filesystem

Comment: A logical solution would be to not use a zip file. Especially for jpegs it's not reducing size, just slowing it down and with that many  files...

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen `it's not reducing size` is not 100% correct, depending on the encoding used and level of compression it could be reducing the file size significantly.

Comment: A zip file is not meant to use used as a filesystem.  Have you ever tested how long it takes to just open a zip file with 500k files?  It's a lot of processing to go into finding where the files are.

Comment: @cmorrissey JPEG doesn't really have many options in encoding or compression and the quality level is handled before that, so in usual cases they really don't compress in any sensible amount.